# Importdata: problems when extracting the data

Tags: matlab, import, ascii

I'm using importdata to extract ASCII files as in the example

```
u(1,1) = importdata('folder/file1_1.asc' ' ', 9)
u(1,2) = importdata('folder/file1_2.asc' ' ', 9)
u(2,1) = importdata('folder/file2_1.asc' ' ', 9)
```

and so on.
Now I have to extract the data. Everything is all right if I do something like

```
a = u(1,1).data(:,2)
```

but if instead I do

```
a(1,1) = u(1,1).data(:,2)
```

then MATLAB returns an error (Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch) and doesn't run. I should extract 272 data sets, therefore I'm doing as above. Is this a bug? What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

After `a = u(1,1).data(:,2)`, what is `size(a)`? I'm betting it's not `[1 1]`! You are trying to put an array, i,e, `data(:,2)` into a single element, i.e. `a(1,1)`. Perhaps you want to put it in a cell array rather?

```
a{1,1} = u(1,1).data(:,2)
```

Otherwise something like this (I'm guessing at your data structure here though)

```
a(1:272,1) = u(1,1).data(:,2)
```

Comment: I tried them both. a{1,1} = u(1,1).data(:,2) returns cell contents assignment to a non-cell array object, while a(1:1001,1) = u(1,1).data(:,2) returns subscripted assignment dimension mismatch. What is strange is that if I type a = u(1,1).data there is no problem: a becomes an array with the elements I need.

Comment: Yes but what is `size(u(1,1).data(:,2))`, unless it is `[1001, 1]` then it's no surprise `a(1:1001,1) = u(1,1).data(:,2)` didn't work. You have to have the same dimensions on both sides of an assignment! As for the error with the cell matrix, make sure you `clear` `a` first. Try this: `clear; u(1,1).data = rand(10)
a{1,1}= u(1,1).data(:,2); b(1:10, 1) = u(1,1).data(:,2)` and you'll see that both methods actually do work